# How to supply keys when calling a bash in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, ssh

Using Ruby I am trying to get the content from a file that is on another machine by doing:

```
run_this = `ssh user@thecomputer cat myfile.txt`
```

The problem is the first time this is run, it is waiting for introducing 'yes' or 'no':

> The authenticity of host 'thecomputer (11.12.134.46)' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

I need to supply the 'yes' automatically without manual intervention

How can I do it?

Comment: hi @Mario Ruiz, can you provide more code please ?

Comment: That's all the code

Comment: Try to avoid backticks when calling, it's the sloppy method. Instead use `system` where each argument is passed in separately: `system("ssh","user@computer", "...")`

Comment: Have a look at the `yes` program. Does `yes | ssh user@thecomputer cat myfile.txt` fixes your problem ?

Comment: doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
run_this = `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@thecomputer cat myfile.txt`
```

Without the StrictHostKeyChecking option turned off, ssh typically defaults to not trusting any new hosts and will interactively prompt the user if there is one, otherwise it will fail.

The problem you are having is very common.  For example, here's someone who was trying to get around this ssh behavior with rsync:

[Bypass Rsync Prompt "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829022/bypass-rsync-prompt-are-you-sure-you-want-to-continue-connecting)